# Errors while trying to connect the test controller using the workstation machine

Tags: c#

I have an install test controller on server A and specify account.

And I want connect it by using visual studio test controller manager by putting IP address of test controller server, but it shows the error "Cannot connect with controller. The server has rejected the client credentials".

How to specify the login credentials to connect to the test controller?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a TestAgent to your test controller:

**To add a test agent to a test controller**:

1. Choose Start, **All Programs, Microsoft Visual Studio, Microsoft Visual Studio Test Agent Configuration Tool**.

The Configure Test Agent dialog box is displayed.

**note:** *You must have a test agent already installed to add it to a test controller. For more information about how to install a test agent, see Install and configure test agents.*

2. If you want to change the way that the test agent is run, choose **Run Options**.

You are presented with two options for how the test agent is going to be run:

**Service** If you do not have to run automated tests that interact with the desktop, such as coded UI tests or creating a video recording when your test runs, under **Run the test agent as**, **select Service**. The test agent will be started as a service. Choose **Next**.

You can now enter the details about the user when the test agent starts as a service.

a. Enter the name in **User name**.

b. Enter the password in **Password**.

please note:

- Null passwords are not supported for user accounts.
- If you want to use the IntelliTrace collector or the network emulation, the user account must be a member of the Administrators group.
- If the agent user name is not in the agent service it will try to add it, which requires permissions on the test controller.
- The user who is trying to use the test controller must be in the test controller's Users account or they will be unable to run the tests against the controller.

taken from msdn [Managing Test Controllers and Test Agents with Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd695837.aspx)

please, address the link for more info.